# MySQL Fetch Month wise total registered users for a calendar year

Tags: mysql, sql, count, report, monthcalendar

I'm trying to fetch month wise total registered users for a calendar year, for instance, 2016. The query needs to take into account the previous registered users till Dec 2015 and add it to the registered users every month in 2016.

Below is my attempt to fetch total registered users, however, it has Two problems:
1. It skips rows where in there are no new registered users
2. It also doesn't count previously registered users when counting the total users.

```
SELECT tots.*, @var := @var + tots.`monthlyUsers` as totalUsers 
FROM (
SELECT m.monthNum,
    YEAR(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) AS `year`,
    MONTH(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) AS `month`,
    COUNT(*) AS `monthlyUsers`
FROM user u
GROUP BY `year`, `month` ) AS tots, (SELECT @var := 0) AS inc
```

The result of this is something like

```
year  month monthlyUsers totalUsers
------------------------------------
2015    1       2              2 
2016    1       3              5
2016    10      1              6
2016    11      2              8
```

How do i overcome these two issues?

**EDIT**
I managed to fetch the records of previous year and add it to the present year data

```
SELECT tots.*, @var := @var + tots.`monthlyUsers` as totalUsers FROM (
SELECT 
    YEAR(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) AS `year`,
    MONTH(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) AS `month`,
    COUNT(*) AS `monthlyUsers`
FROM  user u
where YEAR(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) ='2016'
GROUP BY `year`, `month` ) AS tots, (SELECT @var from (select @var :=count(u.id ) from  user u where year(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) < '2016') as var) AS inc
```

This will fetch me

```
year  month monthlyUsers totalUsers
------------------------------------
2016    1       3              5
2016    10      1              6
2016    11      2              8
```

But my expected result is

```
year  month monthlyUsers totalUsers
------------------------------------
2016    1       3              5
2016    2       0              5
2016    3       0              5  
2016    4       0              5
2016    5       0              5
2016    6       0              5  
2016    7       0              5
2016    8       0              5
2016    9       0              5  
2016    10      1              6
2016    11      2              8
2016    12      0              8
```

Comment: can you add sample data with datatype and expected result  ? also mention DBMS.

Comment: What does the `months` table look like?

Comment: actually i tried creating a months table with month numbers, since it didn't fetch me all the results i decided to remove it

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper `JOIN` syntax.  At least one problem is that you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT um.*, 
       (@var := @var + COALESCE(um.monthlyUsers, 0)) as totalUsers 
FROM months m LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT m.monthNum,
             YEAR(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) AS `year`,
             MONTH(from_unixtime(u.createdDate)) AS `month`,
             COUNT(*) AS `monthlyUsers`
      FROM user u
      GROUP BY `year`, `month`
     ) um
     ON m.monthNum = um.monthNum CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @var := 0) AS inc
ORDER BY `year`, `month`;
```

I'm not sure how to add in the rest of the users.  This query doesn't seem to be filtering any out, although the `JOIN` condition should probably include the year as well.

Comment: actually i tried creating a months table with month numbers, since it didn't fetch me all the results i decided to remove it

Comment: your query doesn't fetch me all the months data

Comment: @gameOne . . . This should fetch one row for each row in `months`.  That seems to be the intent that you want.